# htaccess RewriteRule: filter certain words

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have

```
RewriteRule ^post/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /post/index.php?$1=$2 [NC]
```

which does what it's supposed to do: take a URL like `post/color/black` and turn that into `post/index.php?color=black`.

The problem is that this also affects things like the stylesheet (located at post/styles/style.css), and other files that really exist.

So the question is: if I know the exact `$_GET` keys that need to be translated, how can I limit the above RewriteRule to only do its magic for those specific keys, but leave everything else untouched?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
^post/([^/]+)/(black|white|...)$
```

or

```
^post/([^/]+)/((?!bad keywords)[^/]+)$
```

Answer (score 3):

You can either:

- Use the `-f` flag to exclude actually existing resources from the rewrite process by adding the following RewriteRules:

  ```
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  ```
- Or store your static resources outside `/post` - this would be best because you can exclude the possibility of collisions with 100% certainty, and you save Apache from looking the file up (which is only relevant with a lot of traffic though).

Comment: Thanks for this Pekka, the `-f` flag is golden and great to know. I do have a case where I'm using an actually existing directory as a GET key though, so I'm going with @The Mask's suggestion for now.

Comment: Also... storing resources outside of `/post` is a good idea, but in this case, it would complicate the file structure because I have different / separate applications running at the lower level... generally I agree with you though.